# Heroku: This feature is not supported by your client version. error from heroku logs

Tags: heroku

What causes this?

It occurred when I try to run `heroku logs`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to update the heroku gem (`gem update heroku`).

Comment: Not for me, I'm running Leopard if it matters and the gem version is heroku (2.4.0)

Comment: Same for me as for Nilloc. I have Heroku 2.4.0, running Lion.

Answer (score 0):

If `gem update heroku` does not work for you, try `heroku update`.

Comment: Gives `heroku update` is only available from Heroku Toolbelt.

Comment: I installed heroku toolbelt.  Then I removed the gem and executable (`gem uninstall heroku`).  Then this began to work.